# Ruby - nokogiri - parse only specific html table

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a HTML doc to parse and read a bunch of stuff from there. The problem is the html has multiple tables in it, and I am only interested in one table. Plus I want to read only the lines that having some useful content. Here is sample html page, there are two tables with no ID, and I want only the second table and only the lines that are useful to humans.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD> I don't want this table </TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD> No No No <br></TD>
  </TR>
....
</TABLE>


<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>04/13/2012 22:51  I want this table </TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD> First - something there <br></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>04/13/2012 23:23  Update from xyz</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD>Second - something here <br></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am trying this code, which is obviously not working. The o/p is not the text I want. It includes both tables, I only want the second table. help!

```
require 'curb'
require 'nokogiri'
c = Curl::Easy.perform("http://server/cgi-bin/page.cgi?id=123456")
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(c.body_str.to_s)
puts html_doc.xpath("//table/tr/td")
```

Comment: Got it! 

`require 'curb'
require 'nokogiri'
c = Curl::Easy.perform("http://server/cgi-bin/page.cgi?id=123456")
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(c.body_str.to_s)
puts html_doc.xpath("//table[2]/tr/td/text()")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the xpath of `//table[2]/tr/td` to get the second table.  If you can change the source of the HTML the best solution would be to provide id attributes for your tables.

Comment: thanks. `html_doc.xpath("//table[2]/tr/td/text()"` got it working. But how do I get individual line from the table? I want this stuff to go in mysql with page \r or \n.

Comment: how do I maintain linebreaks before adding to mysql?

Comment: instead of calling `text()` you can call `inner_html()` on the nokogiri nodes which will just give you the raw text inside.  You will have to call inner_html on each td element though.